# Variadic templates & multiple inheritance

Tags: c++11, multiple-inheritance, variadic-templates

I'm struggling with multiple inheritance with variadic templates.

This is my code so far:

```
template <typename U>
    class id_map {
    public:
    std::vector<U> vec_;
};
```

now I want to initialize another class, which inherits multiple times from id_map, something like this:

```
template<typename ... T>
class constant_allkey_map : public id_map<T> ... {
private:
public:
    template <typename U>
    void push_back(U i) {
        id_map<U>::vec_.push_back(i);
    }
};
```

This works and I can access it just fine:

```
constant_allkey_map<int, long> cakm;
cakm.push_back<int>(1);
```

It fails when I try something like this:

```
constant_allkey_map<int, int> cakm;
```

with error

```
"duplicate base type id_map<int> invalid".
```

I did some reading and it seems I'm supposed to extend id_map templates with id parameter:

```
template <size_t i_, typename U>
class id_map ...
```

but I'm not sure how to pass that id in in inheritance part:

```
template<typename ... T>
class constant_allkey_map : public id_map<T> ... {
```

Can someone please help me? Of if I'm doing this entirely wrong, point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are you expecting `cakm.push_back(1);` to do when `cakm` is `constant_allkey_map<int,int>`?

Comment: I would be happy with cakm.push_back<0>(1);, cakm.push_back<1>(1); just as tupple is used, but don't know how to implemenent that.. basically that is my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think inheritance is the right thing here. Therefor I'm proposing the following method to achieve what you want:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template <typename U>
class id_map
{
public:
  typedef U value_type;

public:
  std::vector<U> vec_;
};

template<typename... T>
class constant_allkey_map
{
private:
  typedef std::tuple<id_map<T>...> tuple_t;

public:
  template<
    std::size_t Idx,
    typename U = typename std::tuple_element<Idx, tuple_t>::type::value_type
  >
  void push_back(U x)
  {
    std::get<Idx>(maps_).vec_.push_back(x);
  }

  template<
    std::size_t Idx,
    typename U = typename std::tuple_element<Idx, tuple_t>::type::value_type
  >
  U get(int i) const
  {
    return std::get<Idx>(maps_).vec_[i];
  }

private:
  tuple_t maps_;
};
```

Usage is pretty straightforward:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
  constant_allkey_map<int, long> cakm;
  cakm.push_back<0>(1);
  cakm.push_back<0>(3);
  cakm.push_back<1>(2);
  cakm.push_back<1>(4);

  std::cout << cakm.get<0>(0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << cakm.get<1>(0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << cakm.get<0>(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << cakm.get<1>(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Here's a [live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af1ad24b61d71ca1)

Basically you just let `std::tuple` do the dirty work for you. You can even just do something like this:

```
template<typename... T>
using constant_allkey_map = std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>;
```

and use std::get directly.